# Show this mapping is onto?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $a\in G$. We deine a function $\varphi_a\colon G\to G$ by $\varphi_a(g) = aga^{-1}.$ a) Show that $\varphi_a$ is an isomorphism from $G$ to itself.

The only part Im having trouble with is the onto part.  I have if $x\in G$, then there exists a $y \in G$ such that $\varphi_a(y) = aya^{-1}=x.$ This is what I need to show right?  I just am having trouble going from here.

Comment: Inner automorphism http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_automorphism

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** Yes, that's what you need to show. Just multiply $x$ by $a$ and $a^{-1}$ to find $y$.

Answer (score 2):

$φ_a(a^{-1}ya) = aa^{-1}yaa^{-1}=y$